# Putting strings inside objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have some more complicated strings than as follow but to put it simple, suppose I have

```
var stats_members = ",\{\"y\"\: 6\}";
var data = 
    [{
                "x": "2012-11-05",
                "y": 6
            },+stats_members+
            ]
          ;
```

When I `console.log(data)`I keep on getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]` Could someone explain why ?

Comment: Your goal isn't obvious, here. So it's hard to fix your code.

Comment: why do you have two `+` (addition, concatenation) symbol with only one operand in your array declaration ?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to eval that string into an object and then just put a reference to it in your new object, with no plus signs.

Comment: @Lepidosteus because, here in fact I have some smarty dyanmically generated code. But to make it simple I put some strings to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments show what you are trying to achieve is unclear.

Also:

```
},+stats_members+
```

should be

```
},+stats_members
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! In fact I have some smarty dyanmically generated code. But to make it simple I put some strings to test

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra **'+'** in the **data** variable declaration.

it should be:

```
var data = [{"x": "2012-11-05", "y": 6 }, stats_members];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stats_members = ",\{\"y\"\: 6\}";
var data = 
    [{
                "x": "2012-11-05",
                "y": 6
            },+stats_members
            ]
          ;
```

That extra plus after "stats_members" is causing problem bro

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some very weird stuff there. To make it very very simple, this is how the parser interprets your code:

```
var data = 
[                         //-> here starts an array literal
{                         //-> here starts an object literal (first array item)
  "x": "2012-11-05",      //-> here is the property x in the object literal
  "y": 6                  //-> here is the property y in the object literal
}                         //-> here ends the object literal
,                         //-> comma separating array items
+stats_members            //-> cast to number by the unary + sign
+                         //-> add something to the value on the previous row
]                         //-> array literal end should not be here, it is expecting something to add
```

If you want to explain exactly what you are trying to do, we could help with a better syntax.